# How to set a different display style for each element of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
G =

10.0000e+000     0.0000e+000     4.0000e+000     2.7013e-009
10.0000e+000    10.0000e+000     1.0000e+000     7.7550e-009
 5.0000e+000     5.0000e+000     2.0000e+000   -15.3223e-009
10.0000e+000    10.0000e+000     3.0000e+000     6.6898e-009
```

but I want to display it like this, with only with specific numbers in scientific notation, is this possible?:

```
G =

10     0     4     2.7013e-009
10    10     1     7.7550e-009
 5     5     2   -15.3223e-009
10    10     3     6.6898e-009
```

Matrix code:

```
x_1=0;  y_1=0;   z_1=0; 
x_2=10; y_2=0;   z_2=4;
x_3=10; y_3=10;  z_3=1;
x_4=5;  y_4=5;   z_4=2;

cT21 =   2.701320e-09 
cT31 =   7.755042e-09 
cT41 =   -1.532233e-08 
cT51 =   6.689788e-09 

format shortEng
G = [x_2 y_2 z_2 cT21; x_3 y_3 z_3 cT31; x_4 y_4 z_4 cT41; x_5 y_5 z_5 cT51]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fprintf('%i %i %i %e \n',G.')
10 0 4 2.701300e-09 
10 10 1 7.755000e-09 
5 5 2 -1.532230e-08 
10 10 3 6.689800e-09
```

by using [`fprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). You select `%i` for each *integer*, and `%e` for each *exponential*. The `/n` takes care of the line break for each row contained in `G`. Note the `G.'`; MATLAB displays in column major order, so `G` has to be transposed first.

Even simpler, select `format shortG` which automatically takes care of all values, regardless of their place in the matrix:

```
format shortG
G =

           10            0            4   2.7013e-09
           10           10            1    7.755e-09
            5            5            2  -1.5322e-08
            5            5            2   6.6898e-09
```